# How can I go back to recent page of history with onPopPage in navigation 2.0

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm practicing the new API, navigation 2.0, for my web project with flutter. I'm quite new to flutter either.

I successfully implemented the routing with navigation 2.0, but still can't figure out how the `onPopPage` works. If I tapped the button to navigate to the sub-page, the back button is automatically generated in the header. So when I clicked the back button in the header, it takes me home.

What if I implement another nested sub-page of the sub page, then I clicked the back button it takes me all the way to the top page, home.

I think it's because of the `onPopPage` function which I added like this. How can I edit this function to work properly. I want the back button to pop the only recent page of navigation history.

```dart
onPopPage: (route, result) {
  if (!route.didPop(result)) {
    return false;
  }

  _currentPath = 'home';
  show404 = false;
  notifyListeners();

  return true;
},
```

Comment: you have `_currentPath = 'home';` and most likely `_currentPath` is used by custom `RouterDelegate.build` method - thats why you alwys go to top page

Comment: @pskink Yes, I guess same. Is there any best example or pattern for this?